# How should I request an embargo on access of my personal data by moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderators, privacy, user-information

I would like to request an embargo on access of my personal information collected by Stack Exchange. This embargo should relate to newly elected moderators of the Academia Stack Exchange site.

As far as I have understood I need to file a complaint with the following person:

> If you have any questions about this policy or our site in general, please contact us at team@stackexchange.com.
>
> Our Data Protection Officer is Adam Francoeur.
>
> Written Inquiries can be sent to:
> Stack Exchange, Inc.
> Attn: Adam Francoeur
> 110 William St, 28th Floor
> New York, NY 10038
> USA

The reason is that I feel violated and unsafe if those new moderators have access to it. There is possible retaliation at stake and implications for a future career in academia. Do I need a reason for restricting access to data from unknown moderators?

As I understood, I need to write a complaint to that person, naming the profiles of users (newly elected moderators) whom I don't want to be able to access my private and collected information. Is that correct?

Comment: Just curious, and I assume you didn't know before asking this, but you don't feel insecure with current mods who are also possible to see your personal information on here?

Comment: @HTTP yes the current moderator team is alright, no problem, only the possible future, I feel unsafe.

Comment: @HTTP: I can't help but notice the remarkable irony of someone with your username posting about security… ;)

Comment: @SSimon what information are you worried about moderators having access to? Couldn't you change/remove/obscure anything you're specifically worried about?

Comment: @Cai I don't really know what are available information about me to moderators?

Comment: Well obviously only either information you've explicitly entered of anything discoverable by your connection (e.g. your IP address)

Comment: why did people edit my question in an unrecognizable way?

Comment: I edited to correct your grammar and use the correct site names that is all. The title wasn't misleading; you're explicitly talking about moderators, it's misleading *without* saying so

Comment: @Cai why you added the parts ( who write letters anyway) I was refering to prospective moderators and not to already elected

Comment: [That was in your initial post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/308039/1)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really just seems to be a personal conflict between two individuals, not anything to do with SE.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding, but if you don't have specific concern about specific types of data, then you don't seem to have standing to make this request?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is currently no way to limit the personally identifiable information (PII) to specific moderators, or to restrict it for a single user account in any way. All moderators that accept the moderator agreement can access certain pieces of information that might reveal your identity.

The only way to make sure that a new moderator won't have access to this data is to delete your entire account on this specific SE site. This will put all PII potentially in your account out of the reach of the moderators.

This is not unprecedented, and there have been several cases of users deleting their accounts because they didn't trust a specific moderator that was about to be elected.

If you still wish to participate on the site, you could create a new, separate account and take care not to add any information that identifies you to it. This means using a non-identifying email address, not connecting your account to Facebook or similar, and never accessing it from IP addresses that could reveal your identity. This is not necessarily trivial, it would be safer to never create any account on the site again.

Comment: Yes, but bulling out user is also not an option, it is also consider crime in usa cyber bulling?

Comment: @SSimon A candidate needs to be a user in good standing to actually become a moderator. If you have evidence of bullying by a candidate, you can contact the SE team (https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and inform them about it. If they consider your evidence convincing, and it represents serious misbehaviour, SE might remove the nomination.

Comment: @SSimon Thought you lived in the EU?  What does Cyber Bulling laws in the states have to do with your rights in the EU.  Additionally, Cyber Bulling isn’t a federal crime, at most, it’s a state crime.  So a citizen in CA (which for this example has a law) can’t be charged with Cyber Bullying if they live in Ohio (which for this example does not)

Comment: @MadScientist this is good suggestion!

Answer (score 22):

I don't think it works like that -  that is to say, you can't pick and choose who gets to see the (limited) personal information out of the current or future moderation team.

If you cannot trust the moderators (who all sign [the same moderator agreement](https://academia.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement)), and this information is necessary for them to perform their duties as a moderator - it might be better not to be on the site at all.

This is covered under the [privacy agreement](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) under

[image]

*If* a moderator's using information that's available to them for "reprisals" - report them to the community team and they'd take action.

That said, this is *no more information* than you would share anywhere else on the internet. Moderators are held to pretty strict standards and we have *no more* than you share, other than an IP address. As a moderator we're told any lookup of PII is logged. There's nothing stopping you from using a distinct, fairly anonymous account with a dedicated, free email address too.

However you *cannot* cherry pick who gets to see your information. Either you choose to engage the community and the mod team as a whole, on the terms you feel comfortable with, or not at all.

(It's been suggested disclosing I'm a moderator is a good idea - I was a pro-tem moderator on Software Recommendations, and I'm a current moderator on Super User)

Comment: I don't have the problem with current moderators. However, under current EU law, I have a right to not provide an agreement to new parties that will be able if elected to access my private data. In this case, two possible ( not yet decided) moderators, I wouldn't like than to have my emails and location, bcs it can endager my career, and I wouldnt let myself be bullied out from SE.

Comment: Are you currently in the EU ? Could you link the law in question - I'm not qualified to see if it applies but I'd think it would be useful. That said, I'm pretty sure you can't selectively pick which moderators can see your PII. I'd also feel that it would be *dangerous* since people can literally pick and choose which mods (or none at all!) can see their information, which would fundamentally damage the system of moderation. *And* your agreement is with SE, not the mod.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding, I don't have the problem with current moderators,  more with the potential one, currently is an election on academia part of SE, I opposed some nomination ower there.

Comment: this is just requested how to limit specific user at this website, access to my information. something like restraining order.

Comment: See, a restraining order is a very specific thing, you'd need a very clear reason for. Now, I've asked two specific questions - whether you're in the EU, cause if you arn't this is moot, and the specific law, since "current EU law" is a very broad scope and one needs to actually read it to provide an informed, if unqualified opinion, and the moment you're slinging law, you want someone who is skilled in the art taking a look at it. So, please provide the specific law you're referring to in the question, and if you're not EU based - you'd likely not have a legal footing at all.

Comment: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/consumers/internet-telecoms/data-protection-privacy/index_en.htm

Comment: Yes, so if I understood you well, I need to write including the law, specific one, and I need to file to police or police section for technological criminal, that I don't consent with SE providing information to prospective moderators, name them... is that it?

Comment: Naw, I'm saying that if you're going to claim certain rights under a law, you really need to cite the specific law, and that you're under said juristiction. I for example cannot/shouldn't be claiming protections under EU law, since I'm based in a non EU country. In addition *nowhere* does that link say that you can request specific folk not have access to your information. In short, I'm questioning the basis of your request. That link talks about consent as a whole.

Comment: yes, the consent that I dont give to new moderators

Comment: @SSimon: It sounds like you're claiming that e.g. if someone dislikes how Patrick at the local MS Ireland support center handled their case, they would be entitled by EU law to demand that that particular individual not handle their PII any more. I really doubt that very much. A corporation's employees (at least, those that meet certain qualifications) are basically interchangeable. You can't demand that an organization make special lists of qualified personnel just for you. "Consent" on the linked page is for a *corporation*, not for their specific staffers.

Comment: That's kind of the point I was trying to make. I'm a little confused to how the link he's posted has any relevance to what he thinks the law is too - there's no mention of that sort of representative/agent specific blocks he's talking about.

Comment: @Ssimon - neither that law, nor the incoming GDPR give you the power to demand usage or non-usage by a particular individual.

Comment: Off the top of my head.... and from what I see on my own account on my site under PII - most of it is what the user has provided and/or can see.

Comment: That is to say, you can use a mostly anoymous login, fake name, generic username, fake birthday....

Comment: @SSimon You give either a blanket agreement to all agents of stack exchange and other third parties mentioned in the forward transfer portion of the privacy policy or you don't. Sounds like you don't (if you don't want a new mod to see that). In that case you can (probably) revoke your agreement and stack exchange can take the necessary steps (delete your account) to fulfill its obligation on that part. Now, you have no _right_ to demand that they accomodate your very specific request by changing their process.

Comment: @Magisch as I said, I need to file complain to police or criminal department?

Comment: If you deliberately allow the user that is under investigation access to data, that is pretty much unacceptable by both standards of law

Comment: SSimon - I think you need to read the relevant laws and regulations as you don't seem to understand the basics.

Comment: You are trying to prevent possible future access to data by an individual, by trying to get SE to enforce a data restriction on him? Just not going to happen dude. You can try and go through a law enforcement route if you have evidence of cyber bullying - but good luck with that if you are in different legal jurisdictions...

Comment: @RoryAlsop the question was edited, I didn ask about old moderators, it refered to new one, prospctive

Comment: That's what I said. Future access.

Comment: @SSimon You do not. You don't get to dictate what SE does. And if you decide to take legal action against SE to make them remove a moderator candidate, they might just delete your account and call it a day. And they can do that if they choose

Comment: As others are saying in different ways: @SSimon you only have 2 options according that law, you may have your ENTIRE ACCOUNT deleted/hidden, or not. There is no legal way for you to force future team members from accessing your info.

Answer (score 9):

There is no legal basis you could demand this - even the upcoming General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), which does give much more control over data to the data subject, does not do this. From a company perspective it would make no sense anyway - they will comply with how they use data, but which member of staff actually does that role. Imagine if every time someone new was hired they had to validate usage of data with every data subject!

Additionally, mods here talk to each other as part of moderating sites, both amongst the mods on a single site, but also with others to ensure balance, appropriateness, openness and clarity. So what you request is physically not going to be possible.

If you don't want to adhere to the data usage as described by Stack Exchange, your only option is to delete your account and not use the site.

Comment: He can revoke his consent to have his data stored by stack and force them to remove all of it, but that's about as far as he can go there, in my opinion. Stack could satisfy that request by deleting his account and disassociating his posts.

Comment: I think that is the only way that request can practically be handled :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop I am thinking of filling request to police about cyberbullying if you have the police report about potential moderator than I think SE will consider revoking that user nomination, I think that is my only option if I wan to keep account

Comment: SSimon - that is not how regulation in this space works at all. You can obviously look at reporting cyberbullying, but it doesn't change the data usage requirements for a company.